# Make forst column letters bold in for loop

Tags: html, shell

I'm trying to print mount point space in a tabular format using html. I need the first column in bold. Please help me.

Here is what I did so far:

```
input="/tmp/mountpoint.txt"
tmpfile="/tmp/tmpfile.html"
output="/tmp/df.out"
df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n > $input
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html><body><table border=1>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td><font color='#00000'>" $i"</td></font>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" > "$tmpfile"
sed -e '10d' $tmpfile > $output`
```

[O/P of my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhOnq.jpg)

Comment: The first row, or the first column? If you mean the first row, use `<th>` (table header) for its cells instead of `<td>`. If you mean the first column, add `td:first-child { font-weight: bold; }` to your CSS.

Comment: Hi Jon,Thank you for answering. How can I put that in a loop?? I'm new to coding, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd11nyfy/4/)

```css
td:first-child{
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='textWord_about'>
  <table border='1'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1111111111111111111111111111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11111111111111111111111111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11111111111111111111111111111111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111111111111111111111111111111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class='directly-follow'>

</div>
```